# How to work out eigenvalues, eigenfunctions, $M$ and $\delta$ for this problem

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, eigenfunctions

Let

$$p(x)= \begin{cases}
M \in \mathbb{R}, & x \in \left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta,\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right) \\
1, & x\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}-\delta)\cup(\frac{1}{2}+\delta,1\right) .
\end{cases}$$

An asymptotic expansion for the equation (known as the Elastic Differential Equation);

$$y'' + \lambda^{2} p(x) y = 0$$

where $\lambda$ is a variable, and $(a,b)=(0,1)$ is;

$$y(x,\lambda)=e^{i\lambda}\int_0^1 \sqrt{p(s)ds}\left[\frac{1}{p(x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1}(d(x)+\frac{e_+}{p(x)^{\frac{1}{4}}})\right]+e^{-i\lambda}\int_0^1 \sqrt{p(s)ds}\left[\frac{-1}{p(x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1}(d(x)-\frac{e_+}{p(x)^{\frac{1}{4}}})\right]+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{\lambda^2})$$

Where $e_+$ is a constant, and;

$$d(x)=\frac{i}{2(p(x))^{\frac{1}{4}}}\int_a^x \frac{5(p'(x))^2}{16(p(x))^{\frac{5}{2}}}dx -\frac{i}{2(p(x))^{\frac{1}{4}}}\int_a^x \frac{p''(x)}{4(p(x))^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$

Now

$$y_1'' + \lambda^2 y_1 = 0, x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)$$

$$y_2'' + \lambda^2 M y_2 = 0, x\in\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta, \frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)$$

$$y_3'' + \lambda^2 y_3 = 0, x\in\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta,1\right)$$

$y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$ have solutions of the form;

$$y_1=a_1 e^{i\lambda x} + b_1 e^{-i\lambda x}$$

$$y_2=a_2 e^{i\lambda\sqrt{M}x} + b_2 e^{-i\lambda\sqrt{M}x}$$

$$y_3=a_3 e^{i\lambda x} + b_3 e^{-i\lambda x}$$Initial value and boundary conditions:

$$y_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)=y_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)$$
$$y_1'\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)=y_2'\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)$$
$$y_2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)=y_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)$$
$$y_2'\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)=y_3'\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)$$
$$y_1(0)=0$$
$$y_3(1)=0$$

Then using these 6 equations I get the system;

$$\begin{bmatrix} g & \frac{1}{g} & -f & -\frac{1}{f} & 0 & 0 \\ i\lambda g & \frac{-i\lambda}{g} & -i\lambda \sqrt{M}f & \frac{i\lambda \sqrt{M}}{f} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & h & \frac{1}{h} & -k & \frac{-1}{k} \\ 0 & 0 & i\lambda\sqrt{M}h & -\frac{i\lambda\sqrt{M}}{h} & -i\lambda k & \frac{i\lambda}{k} \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \\ a_2 \\ b_2 \\ a_3 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}=0$$

Where;

$$f= e^{i\lambda \sqrt{M}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)}$$
$$g= e^{i\lambda \left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)}$$
$$h= e^{i\lambda \sqrt{M}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)}$$
$$k= e^{i\lambda \left(\frac{1}{2}+\delta\right)}$$

What I am trying to do;

Deriving formulae for $M$ and $\delta$, then hence obtain eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for $y(x,\lambda)$.

I have done work on this, and will provide what I have done in the future via updates to this question;

Attempt 1);

Simplifying the first matrix using Gaussian elimination, then have 6 equations;

$a_1=0$, $b_1=0$,  $a_2=0$, $b_2=0$, $a_3=0$, $b_3=0$

Hence $y_1 = y_2 = y_3 =0$, but no apparent useful results to me for $M$ and $\delta$.

Attempt 2);

--To be updated--

Using the fact that the determinant of the 1st matrix is equal to 0 for the system to have solutions, I have then expanded this determinant to give the following equation;

$$-8\sqrt{M}+(1-\sqrt{M})\frac{fg}{hk}+(1+2\sqrt{M}-M)\frac{hk}{fg}+(1+2\sqrt{M}+M)(\frac{fk}{gh}+\frac{gh}{fk})=0$$

This then simplifies to;

--To be updated--

$$a^{2}s^{4a\delta}-a^{2}s^{2\delta(2a-2)}-a^{2}s^{2\delta(a+1)}-8(a+1)s^{2a\delta}+(2-a)=0$$

where $M \ge 0 \in \Bbb R$, $a=\sqrt{M}+1 \in \Bbb R$, $s=e^{i\lambda} \in \Bbb C$, $a \ge 1$, $\delta \in \Bbb R$.

(I have [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1923227/) where I ask for help on this equation.)

Attempt 3)

Using the fact that the determinant of the characteristic matrix is equal to 0 for eigenvalues;

--To be updated--

$$\det\begin{bmatrix} f-X & \frac{1}{f} & -g & -\frac{1}{g} \\ i\lambda \sqrt{M}f & \frac{-i\lambda \sqrt{M}}{f}-X & -i\lambda g & \frac{i\lambda}{g} \\ h & \frac{1}{h} & -k-X & -\frac{1}{k} \\ i\lambda\sqrt{M}h & -\frac{i\lambda\sqrt{M}}{h} & -i\lambda k & \frac{i\lambda}{k}-X \end{bmatrix}=0$$

where $X$ is an eigenvalue.

I have then got a cubic equation in $X$ , from simplifying this;

$$a'X^3 + a''X^2 + a^{(3)}X + a^{(4)} + a^{(5)} + a^{(6)}=0 $$

The coefficients of this cubic equation, $a^{(n)}$ though are complex functions of $\lambda, M, f, g, h$ and $k$.

Questions / help requested;

1) Derivation of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, what this means for $M$ and $\delta$, and an example illustrating this.

2) Derivation of formulae for $M$ and $\delta$.

3) What happens to $M$ & $\delta$ as $\lambda$ tends to infinity?

4) I am not sure which method - Attempt 1 / Attempt 2 / Attempt 3 is more fruitful. Am I approaching this in a sound way? What would be better method(s) if any?

Comment: You want to use the `\ `, for example `\frac{123}{abc}` for $\frac{123}{abc}$.

Comment: back to the Latex-school^^ Read carefully I tried to edit better tex, but I'm not sure with your $\mathcal{U}$

Comment: Ok thanks for the editing. By the \U I mean the boolean OR

Comment: I'm guessing there is a $p(x)$ somewhere in the original ode? Please clean up the question so the original problem is clearly stated.

Comment: @pragabhava question significantly updated.

Comment: @unseen_rider You're still missing boundary conditions. What happens at $y_1(0)$ and $y_2(1)$?

Comment: @pragabhava Boundary conditions were not originally specified for $y_1(0)$ and $y_2(1)$. I have added what I thought would be them.

Comment: @unseen_rider You need boundary conditions, otherwise the ode is not well defined. You have three regions: $(0,\tfrac{1}{2}-\delta)$, $(\tfrac{1}{2}-\delta, \frac{1}{2}+\delta)$ and $(\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta,1)$; therefore, you'll have three solutions, one for each region. Since the ode is of second order, each one of this solutions will have two arbitrary constants, i.e. you'll have to determine six constants. Finally, you have four continuity conditions, leaving you with two constants. This two constants must be determined using boundary conditions.

Comment: @pragabhava what do you mean by the continuity conditions in relation to this question?

Comment: @unseen_rider The conditions \begin{align}y_1(\tfrac{1}{2}-\delta) &= y_2(\tfrac{1}{2}-\delta), \qquad y_1'(\tfrac{1}{2}-\delta) = y_2'(\tfrac{1}{2}-\delta), \\ y_2(\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta) &= y_3(\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta), \qquad y_2'(\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta) = y_3'(\tfrac{1}{2}+\delta).\end{align} You should take a look at [the potential well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) or [the potential barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier) to see what I'm talking about. If I have time later, I'll answer the question.

Comment: The conditions at $x=0$ and $x = 1$ don't make any sense; $y_1$ is not defined in $x = 1$ and $y_2$ is not defined in $x = 0$.

Comment: @pragabhava - sorry I don't understand why you say those are not well defined there?

Comment: Because of $p(x)$, you have three regions:
\begin{matrix}
y_1'' + \lambda y_1 = 0 & & 0 < x < \frac{1}{2}-\delta,\\
y_2'' + \lambda M y_2 = 0 & & \frac{1}{2}-\delta < x < \frac{1}{2}+\delta,\\
y_3'' + \lambda y_3 = 0 & & \frac{1}{2}+\delta < x < 1.\\
\end{matrix}
You want a $C^1(0,1)$ solution, so $y_1(\frac{1}{2}-\delta) = y_2(\frac{1}{2}-\delta)$, $y_1'(\frac{1}{2}-\delta) = y_2'(\frac{1}{2}-\delta)$, $y_2(\frac{1}{2}+\delta) = y_3(\frac{1}{2}+\delta)$, $y_2'(\frac{1}{2}+\delta) = y_3'(\frac{1}{2}+\delta)$. You need boundary conditions, i.e., $y_1(0) = 0$ and $y_3(1) = 0$ (Dirichlet).

Comment: @pragabhava how do you know that $y_1(0)$ and $y_3(1)$ are $0$ and not another number?

Comment: I don't! It's an example, as there are missing boundary conditions! Do you know your boundary conditions? Dirichlet? Neumann? Mixed? Periodic? Initial? Are you working with a string? Is it a quantum mechanics calculation? What is the context? Unless you provide boundary conditions (two conditions involving $x = 0$ and $x = 1$), the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: @pragabhava Ok I have started updating my question following your comments. Thank you so far. I decided to use the boundary conditions stated as an example. The context is that I am looking at high frequency approximations of $\lambda$ - ray theory and its applications to mechanics. The question follows my final year project done a few years ago, and now I worked through this following where I got to in the project. What else would I need to solve this problem in the current form?

Comment: @unseen_rider Later on the week I'll post an answer :)

Comment: @pragabhava when you have time, please post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (translated) problem at hand is the following:

> We are looking for a $C^1\big(-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\big)$ solution of the problem
>   $$
> y''(x) + \lambda^2 p(x) y(x) = 0, \quad -\tfrac{1}{2} < x < \tfrac{1}{2},
> $$
>   $$
> y\big(\pm\tfrac{1}{2}\big) = 0,
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> p(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }\big|x\big| > \delta, \\ M & \text{if }\big|x\big| < \delta, \end{cases}
> $$
>   $0< \delta < \tfrac{1}{2}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

Due the definition of $p(x)$, we have three regions: $(-\tfrac{1}{2},-\delta)$, $(-\delta,\delta)$ and $(\delta,\tfrac{1}{2})$. This means that we are looking for
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases} y_1(x) & \text{if } -\tfrac{1}{2} < x < - \delta,\\ y_2(x) & \text{if } -\delta < x < \delta,\\ y_3(x) & \text{if } \delta < x < \tfrac{1}{2},\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
y_1\big(-\tfrac{1}{2}\big) = 0,\quad
y_1(-\delta) = y_2(-\delta),\quad
y_1'(-\delta) = y_2'(-\delta),
$$
$$
y_2(\delta) = y_3(\delta),\quad
y_2'(\delta) = y_3'(\delta),\quad
y_3\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\big) = 0.
$$

Now, it's fairly simple to see that
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases} A_1 \sin\left[\lambda\big(x + \tfrac{1}{2}\big)\right] & \text{if } -\tfrac{1}{2} < x < - \delta,\\ B_1 \sin\left[\lambda\sqrt{M}x\right] + B_2 \cos\left[\lambda\sqrt{M}x\right] & \text{if } -\delta < x < \delta,\\ C_1 \sin\left[\lambda\big(x - \tfrac{1}{2}\big)\right] & \text{if } \delta < x < \tfrac{1}{2},\end{cases}
$$
is a solution of the ODE that satisfies the boundary conditions. Writing the continuity conditions in matrix form, we have that
$$
\small
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta \right) \lambda \right] & \sin \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & -\cos \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & 0 \\
 \lambda  \cos \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta \right) \lambda \right] & -\lambda \sqrt{M} \cos \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & -\lambda \sqrt{M} \sin \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & 0 \\
 0 & \sin \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & \cos \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & -\sin \left[\left(\delta -\frac{1}{2}\right) \lambda \right] \\
 0 & \lambda  \sqrt{M} \cos \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & -\lambda \sqrt{M} \sin \left[\delta  \lambda  \sqrt{M}\right] & -\lambda  \cos \left[\left(\delta -\frac{1}{2}\right) \lambda \right]
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}A_1 \\ B_1 \\ B_2 \\ C_1 \end{pmatrix} = 0.
$$
The system has nontrivial solutions iff the matrix determinant is equal to zero, i.e.,
$$
\small
-\frac{\lambda^2}{4}\begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} -\sin\left[(2\delta v + 1)\lambda\right] & \sin \left[(u + v)\delta \lambda\right] \\ \sin \left[(u + v)\delta \lambda\right] & -\sin\left[(2\delta u - 1)\lambda\right] \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix} = 0,
$$
where $u = \sqrt{M} + 1$ and $v = \sqrt{M}-1$.
It's clear that $\lambda = 0$ would lead to a trivial solution, so $\lambda = 0$ is not an *eigenvalue*. Hence, we are looking for solutions to the transcendental equation
$$\label{eigeq}
\small
\begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}-\sin\left[(2\delta v + 1)\lambda\right] & \sin \left[(u + v)\delta \lambda\right] \\ \sin \left[(u + v)\delta \lambda\right] & -\sin\left[(2\delta u - 1)\lambda\right] \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix} = 0. \tag{1}
$$
We see that taking $M = 1$ or $\delta = 0$ leads to the relation
$$
\sin \sqrt{\lambda} = 0,
$$
which is to be expected.

For the full characterization of the problem, you'll need to study the zeros of \eqref{eigeq}.

I'm hoping that due the symmetric form of eq. \eqref{eigeq}, something more can be said, but I haven't had the time to look into it. Quick asymptotics show that, if $\sqrt{M} \gg \delta$, the *eigenvalues* are such that $\lambda_n \sim \frac{n \pi}{2 \delta \sqrt{M}}$. For large eigenvalues, you can use an educated combination of the [WKB approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation) and the [Sturm–Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem), or variational methods (see Friedman's *Principles and techniques of applied mathematics*, for example).

Comment: 1st question: where does the  $-\frac{1}{4}$ in $\frac{\lambda^2}{4}\begin{pmatrix} u\\v \end{pmatrix}^T$ come from?

Comment: 2nd question: "Quick asymptotics show that, if $M≫δ$, the eigenvalues are such that $\lambda_n \sim \frac{n \pi}{2 \delta M}$" how did you derive this?

Comment: @unseen_rider The factor comes out while you complete trigonometric sums. Regarding the asymptotics, if $\sqrt{M} \gg \delta$, then $(2\delta u - 1) \to 2 \delta \sqrt{M}$, $(2 \delta v + 1) \to 2 \delta \sqrt{M}$ and $(u + v)\delta \to 2\delta\sqrt{M}$ (I was missing a square root).

Comment: You have a typo in the first region - I believe it should be $(-\frac{1}{2},-\delta)$ ie starting at negative half

Comment: How did you derive $y(x)$ in terms of Sines and Cosines?

Comment: @unseen_rider Fixed the typo. Thanks. I used the trig. representation of the solution for the [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator). You could work with complex exponentials _as well_. Is a matter of choice. I didn't gave it much thought, because my intention was to show you how it's done, but it might worth a try, specially if you're working with wave functions.

Comment: Ok I'm familiar with the harmonic oscillator, but can't see / remember how your trig representation follows?

Comment: @unseen_rider Is the solution of equation $y'' + \omega^2 y = 0$. Not trying to be offensive here, but you really have to study if you can't put [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) to use here.